# How to display results from two tables using JOIN in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

So I have 3 tables that are going to be used for this problem.

Table Name: **users**

columns: USER_ID(INT & PRIMARY KEY), USER_EMAIL(VARCHAR)

Table Name: **teams**

columns: TEAM_ID(INT & PRIMARY KEY), TEAM_NAME(VARCHAR)

Table Name: **user_teams**

columns: USER_TEAM_ID(INT & PRIMARY KEY), USER_ID(INT & FOREIGN KEY from **users**), TEAM_ID(INT & FOREIGN KEY from **teams**)

I am trying to display everyone's email or USER_EMAIL that is on a team.

### For example:

**Team 1**

user with the USER_IDs 6 and 8 are on the team

TEAM_ID: 1

I want to echo the user's emails associated with those USER_IDs on Team 1.

I feel that I would have to use a JOIN to make this happen but am unsure of how to go about doing it with codeigniter.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need to format your question properly.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty straight forward. In your model,

```
$this->db->select('users.USER_EMAIL')
->from('users')
->join('user_teams', 'users.USER_ID = user_teams.USER_ID')
->join('teams', 'teams.TEAM_ID = user_teams.TEAM_ID')
->where('teams.TEAM_ID', $teamID); //In your case 1 here
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```